# Slide-to-the-right submenu after clicking a button

Tags: html, css, web

I want to make a control panel for the admin part of my website. The control panel I developed consists of several buttons. What I need is whenever I click one of the buttons, that option's sub-menu will appear right next to it. For example, I have "My Account" as one of the main options. If I click on the "My Account" button, its sub-menu (with Update Profile and Change Password etc.) will appear.

Here's the code for the control panel:

```
    <div class="main-area">
    <div class="control-panel">
    <h1>Admin Control Panel</h1>
    <button class="categories">My Account ►</button><br /><br />
    <button class="categories">System Users ►</button><br /><br />
    <button class="categories">Applicants ►</button><br /><br />
    <button class="categories">Blacklist ►</button>
    <br /><br />
    <button class="categories">Jobs ►</button><br /><br />
    <button class="categories">Requirements ►</button><br />
    <br />
    <button class="categories">Reports ►</button>
```

Here's the CSS part:

```
body {
      font-family: arial;
      background-color: #0F8DC7;
    }

    .control-panel {
      border: solid 1px #000;
      padding: 15px;
      border-radius: 15px;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px;
      width: 300px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      height: 370px;
      background-color: #FFE400;
    }

    .main-area {
      width: 500px;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .categories{
      width: 200px;
    }
```

Hoping for some answers not involving JavaScript.

Comment: Can you provide fiddle? Show us what have you tried yet for `animation`?

Comment: You have provided the menu items only, where's your submenu items???

Comment: That's what I'm asking for help. How can I make my submenu items appear after clicking one of those buttons. All I see in the Internet all involve JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It's just a demo, I haven't styled your code for a better view.*

You have to use [***css :hover***](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) to achieve this functionality. And put your button(menuItem) and submenuItems(li) inside "ul" tag like this,

```
<ul>
    <button class="categories">My Account ►</button><br /><br />
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

Add this css code ,

```
.main-area ul li{
    display : none;
}

.main-area ul:hover li{
    display : block;
    background:blue; 
    height:auto; 
    width:8em;
}
```

Style your submenu items as you want.

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/xsL5n7ps/)

Comment: How can I make the subitems appear on the right side?

Comment: change your style to display the "li" submenus on right side. Shouldn't be very hard I guess.